# Select Statement DrillDown

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, t-sql

I have a Select Statement Like this..

```
Select * From A Join B on A.ID = B.ID
 And A.Gener = 'M'
 And A.Age = 21
 And B.School = 'Bluh'   
--- many more AND Clauses
```

now these "AND" Clauses are dynamic, they will be build based upon user selection within my  vb.net web application....

for example...

```
if gener.text <> "" Then
   qry = qry & " And A.Gender='M'"
```

I dont really want to build my SQL query on the fly like this. is there a way of doing it better using LINQ or something else?

my actual SQL Query will contain up to 30 dynamic AND's (Based upon user selection).

please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote a good pair of articles on [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - if you want to push this all down to the database level. Short version is - with modern SQL Server, you can just include all of the clauses, such as `(A.Gener = @Gener or @Gener IS NULL)`, use the `RECOMPILE` option, and the server will generate an efficient plan based on whether or not the `@Gener` parameter is `NULL` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would change it this way

```
Select * From A Join B on A.ID = B.ID
 And (A.Gener = @arg1 or @arg1 is null)
 And (A.Age = @arg2 or @arg2 is null)
 And (B.School = @arg3 or @arg3 is null)
```

--- many more AND Clausesju

this way if you pass null values into procedure they would be logicly ignored - dont know if it works in your case

definetly building dynamic tsql query application side is a invitation for sql injection

Answer (score 1):

Use for every statement:

> qry = qry & " And (A.Gender='" & gender.Text & " ' OR '" & gender.Text
>   & "' = '' ) "

Comment: I am afraid this wont really work for me, i am almost doing it like this already...i will have different data types such as DATE|INT|BOOLEAN...and if there is no DATE specified then I dont need that AND clause.